# Implementing UIView in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation, avplayer

I am trying to implement a video player in SwiftUI via a UIView following this tutorial: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/avplayer-swiftui-b87af6d0553

Unfortunately the video is not displaying, I have AVFoundation imported so I am not sure of the issue. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Here are the classes I created:

```
class PlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    
    init(frame: CGRect, urlString: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        player.play()
    
        playerLayer.player = player
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
     }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
     override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
     }
}

struct VideoPlayerUIView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var frame: CGRect
    var urlString: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        return PlayerUIView(frame: self.frame, urlString: self.urlString)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

Here I how I am using the implementation in SwiftUI:

```
var body: some View {
      Text("Videos")
      VideoPlayerUIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300), urlString: urlString)
}
```

This was the output (no video)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JAw9.png)

Comment: Code works fine for me. Are you sure your `URL` string is valid? Otherwise, it'll hit the `return` in the `guard` statement without throwing an error.

Comment: I checked with breakpoints, the URL is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did everything right here.

The only thing that is causing error is how you are process the URL.

Try initialising the player like this instead

```
     let player = AVPlayer(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: urlString, withExtension: "mp4")!)
```

Change the extension according to the format you are using. Remember, here I am force wrapping the optional. So, if you give a wrong urlString or have a video extension other than mp4, the app will crash

Comment: What if the URL points to a server rather than video locally?

Comment: `let asset = AVAsset(url: URL(string: "https://media.giphy.com/media/11mwBM4qjFBBwA/giphy.mp4")!)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)`

Initialise the player something like this 

Refer to [this article](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-set-up-video-streaming-in-your-app-with-avplayer-7dc21bb82f3) for more